# PHP replace common words from my file

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried to make a tool in which you input a website and when you click the submit button it cURLS all the text.

After all the cURLing, stripping it from tags, and counting the words. It's eventually an array named `$frequency`. If I echo it using `<pre>` tags it will show me everything just fine! (NOTE: I'm placing the contents in a file, `$homepage = file_get_contents($file);` and this is what I work with in my code, I don't know if this matters or not)

However i don't really care if the word `or` is seen 200 times in a website, I only want the important words. So i have made an array with all the common words. Which is set eventually in the `$common_words` variable. But i can't seem to find a way to replace all words found in the  `$frequency`  to replace them with `""` if they are found in the `$common_words` as well.

I've found this piece of code after some research:

```
$string = 'sand band or nor and where whereabouts foo';
$wordlist = array("or", "and", "where");

foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}

$string = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

If I copy paste this it works fine, removing the `or, and, where` from the string.
But replacing `$string` with `$frequency` or replacing `$wordlist` with `$common_words` will either not work or throw me an error like: `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

I hope i've formulated my question properly, if not. Please tell me!

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Alright, i've narrowed down the problem alot. First of all i forgot the `&` inside the  `foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {`

But as it was counting all the words, the words it has replaced are all still counted. See those 2 screenshots to see what I mean: http://imgur.com/oqqZR3h,xHEZKRz#0

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but how does your regexp work ? Shouldn't it be something like /or|and|where/ ? I haven't done PHP in a while so I'm not used to such a crude API, but from here it doesn't look like that's what you're doing.

Comment: @Michael The piece of code near the end is what i've found on the internet, if i copy paste and run this code it works fine, it removes the words or, and and where from the string. But replacing the $string and $wordlist with my own variables isn't working

Comment: its working for me, even if i change the wordlist.I dont really understand what is the issue with you? its all very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you wan't to know how many occurrences each word has by ignoring the so called *common words*.

Assuming that `$url` is the page you will be running against and `$common_words` is your common words array, here is what you can do:

```
// Get the page content's and strip the html tags
$contents = strip_tags( file_get_contents($url) );

// This will split the words from the contents, creating an array with each word in it
preg_match_all("/([\w]+[']?[\w]*)\W/", $contents, $words);

$common_words = array('or', 'and', 'I', 'where');

$frequency = array();

// Count occurrences
$frequency = array_count_values($words[0]);
unset($words); // Release all that memory

var_dump($frequency);
```

At this point you will have an associative array with each *not common word* and a count showing the number of occurrences of the given word.

**UPDATE**

A bit more about the RegEx. We need to match word. The easiest way possible is: `(\w+)`. But that won't match words like `I've` or `haven't` (Notice the `'`). That was my point of making it more complicated. Also, `\w` doesn't support dashes for words like in `6-year-old`.

So I created a subgroup which should match words characters including dashed and single quotes in a word.

```
(?:\w'|\w|-)
```

The `?:` part on the beginning is `do not match` or `do not include in the results`. That is since all I am doing is grouping the options for word contents. To mach an entire word the RegEx will match one or more of the subgroup above:

```
((?:\w'\w|\w|-)+)
```

So the RegEx `preg_match_all()` line should be:

```
preg_match_all("/((?:\w'\w|\w|-)+)/", $contents, $words);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works like 50% for me. I will try to play around with it untill it fits within my excisting code. Bear with me I will accept your answer if i can get it to work =/

Comment: Alright, i'm very lost right now. I have trouble fitting the code i had, and the code from you together. The code you provided works. But somehow in my other code it provided me with the good words, and using your code it gives me words for example: `hello.` or `good ` <- note the space after the word. This makes it impossible to filter out words i don't need. While in my other code it showed me much better words. I don't know if you would like to see the code i had previously?

Comment: If you're interested, this was my previous code, http://pastie.org/private/f5imeqpzi6oz7vuvstdxw

Comment: @DejaVu Take a look the updated version of my answer.

Comment: I was testing it against `I am only in this position 'cuz of my 6-year-old little brother who wouldn't listen to me.`, which I think covers most of the corner cases I came up with.

Comment: Alright, this looks good. Is there a quick guide or something you recommend with regex? For me it's put some random characters put together right now :)

Comment: Oh! `array_count_values` is a good idea, instead of my foreach statement.

Comment: @DejaVu Try http://rubular.com. Primarily I am using the quick reference below while testing my regular expressions. Also http://www.regular-expressions.info.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I hope i'm not getting to pushy right now. But you didn't include the $common_words? Or I am I just being stupid. And how can I make it so that it doesn't show what's inside the tags? If I for example use `strip_tags( file_get_contents($file), '<li>');` the most common word in the file is `li` with 308 uses on  a random wikipedia page. And where do some random words come from? For example `ext` has 15 uses while with control+f there are none. or just the `0` has 38 uses while i can find none. I used [this](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Gore) page for example.

Comment: Btw you've helped me out a great deal already, im more than gratefull =] just those tiny issues that are a mystery to me

Comment: Oh wait, replacing the foreach with the array_count took the $common words away, so now it won't check the common words anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed $wordlist with $mywordlist. still its working!

```
<?php
$string = 'sand band or nor and where whereabouts foo';
$wordlist = array("or", "and", "where");
$mywordlist=array("sand","band");
foreach ($mywordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}

$string = preg_replace($mywordlist, '', $string);
var_dump($string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do simply like this:

```
$common_words = "foo baq etc etc";

$str = "foo bar baz"; // input

foreach (explode(" ", $common_words) as $word){
   $str = strtr($str, $word, "");
}
```